# How do I copy contents of an array and place it to a 2D array? C++

Tags: c++, arrays

a beginner computer science student here. The main task of the program is to create 3 options for the user, the user will input numbers (how many numbers depends on the user's choice) then arrange the user input to bubble assortment, selection sort, and heapsort, and then the arranged user input will then be turned to a 2D array.

The problem is I am stuck on turning 1D array to a 2D array. How do I copy my 1D array and place the contents of it onto the 2D array? I have tried various codes and tutorials online and it still doesn't work on my code.

Also should I try getting user input, turning it to 2D array, and then arranging it to bubble, selection, and heapsort? Would that be easier? Thanks.

Here is the output of the program:

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int i;
const int sizeRow = 4;
const int sizeCol = 5;
int row, col;
int list[20];
char getMenu(char and);
void getOutput(int list[], int dim);
void getInput(int list[], int dim);
void getBubble(int list[], int dim);
void getBubbleDown(int list[], int dim);
void convert2DimSort(int xlist[][sizeCol]);
void get2Dout(int xlist[][sizeCol]);

int main() {
  int sagot;
  char ans;
  int choice;
  string ide;
  bool yn = 0;

  do {
    sagot = getMenu(ans);
    cin >> and;

    switch (ans) {
    case '1': // bubble sort
    {
      int dim = 20;
      int list[dim];
      int xlist[sizeRow][sizeCol];
      int newlist[sizeRow][sizeCol];

      getInput(list, dim);
      getBubbleDown(list, dim);

      newlist[sizeRow][sizeCol] = list[dim];

      convert2DimSort(newlist);

      break;
    }

    case '2': // convert2dimsort
    {
      int dim = 20;
      int list[dim];

      getInput(list, dim);
      break;
    }

    case '3': // heapsort
    {
      int dim = 10;
      int list[dim];

      getInput(list, dim);

      break;
    }

    case '4': {
      cout << "bye bitch";
      return 0;
    }
    }

    cout << endl << "try again? y/n: ";
    cin >> ide;

    if (ide == "y") {
      yn = 1;
    } else {
      yn = 0;
    }
  } while (yn == 1);
  return 0;
}

char getMenu(char ans) {
  cout << "-----SORTING-----" << endl
       << "[1] BUBBLE SORT" << endl
       << "[2] SELECTION SORT" << endl
       << "[3] HEAP SORT" << endl
       << "[4] QUIT" << endl
       << endl
       << "----------" << endl
       << "Enter your choice: ";
}

void getInput(int list[], int dim) {
  cout << "enter number: " << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
    cout << "loc[" << i << "] ";
    cin >> list[i];
  }
}

// used as a tester
void getOutput(int list[], int dim) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    cout << list[i] << " ";
    list[dim];
  }
}

void getBubble(int list[], int dim) {
  int j;
  int temp;

  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < (20 - i - 1); j++) {
      if (list[j] < list[j + 1]) {
        int temp = list[j];
        list[j] = list[j + 1];
        list[j + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}

// not used yet
void getBubbleDown(int list[], int dim) {
  int j;
  int temp;

  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < (20 - i - 1); j++) {
      if (list[j] < list[j + 1]) {
        int temp = list[j];
        list[j] = list[j + 1];
        list[j + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}

void convert2DimSort(int xlist[][sizeCol]) {
  int index = 0;
  for (row = 0; row < sizeRow; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < sizeCol; col++) {
      xlist[row][col] = list[index++];
    }
  }

  for (row = 0; row < sizeRow; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < sizeCol; col++) {
      cout << setw(7) << xlist[row][col];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code [doesn't](https://godbolt.org/z/xoE1TGGqv) compile

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot use `and` as a variable name in `char getMenu(char and);`, since it is a keyword.

From what i can understand, your `convert2DimSort` is taking a 2D array input. There should be no need for that unless you are going to be using its reference value.

Other then that it looks like it should work.
So just to be clear is the problem that you are not able to compile the problem or that you're getting wrong output? Because for me here it doesn't even compile.